# When do objects in the image of a functor $G$ have a unique action as algebras over the codensity monad of $G$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads, kan-extension

Let $G:\mathcal{B}\longrightarrow \mathcal{A}$ be some functor which admits a right Kan extension along itself, $(\operatorname{Ran}_G G, \eta:\operatorname{Ran}_G G \circ G \rightarrow G)$.

The functor $\operatorname{Ran}_G G : \mathcal{A}\rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ is canonically a monad, for a unit $u:1_{\mathcal{A}}\rightarrow \operatorname{Ran}_G G$ and multiplication $m: \operatorname{Ran}_G G \circ \operatorname{Ran}_G G \rightarrow\operatorname{Ran}_G G$ obtained from the universal property of Kan extensions: this is called the codensity monad of $G$.

Given any $B$ in $\mathcal{B}$, the object $G(B)$ can be viewed as an algebra over the codensity monad of $G$, namely as the algebra $(G(B),\eta_B)$, where $\eta$ is the natural transformation associated to the Kan extension.

***Is it known when $(G(B),\eta_B)$ is in some sense the unique $\operatorname{Ran}_G G$-algebra structure that can be put on $G(B)$?***

My question is motivated by the following examples investigated in http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/28/13/28-13.pdf:

- If G is the inclusion of $\operatorname{FinSet}$ in $\operatorname{Set}$, then the Eilenberg-Moore category of the codensity monad of $G$ is the category of compact Hausdorff spaces. Now, if we pick a finite set $B$ there is only one topology we can put on it so that it becomes $T_1$, namely the discrete topology, hence there is only one "way" of regarding $B$ as a compact Hausdorff space.
- Fix some field $k$. If G is the inclusion of $\operatorname{FDVect}$ in $\operatorname{Vect}$, then the Eilenberg-Moore category of the codensity monad of $G$ is the category of linearly compact $k$-vector spaces. Again, if we pick a finite dimensional vector space $B$ there is only one topology we may endow it with so that it becomes linearly topologised and $T_1$, namely the discrete topology. So, as before, there is only one "way" of seeing a finite dimensional vector space as a linearly compact vector space.

Comment: Did you see 5.2, 5.3, 5.4 in the reference you mention?

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti Thank you for pointing that out. I did not know that when $G$ is fully faithful, then the natural transformation $\operatorname{Ran}_G F \circ G \rightarrow F$ associated to the Kan extension is a isomorphism.